# Image not Uploading while using multer single image input option?

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I am using multer to upload single image...

```
router.post('/register', upload.any(), function(req,res,next){
var img = req.files;
}
```

If I print the img the it is showing the object properly( originalname, mimeType, size etc) but when i trying to add the propertys in individual variable ( originalname = img.originanae;/req.files.originalename;) then originalname is showing undefined.
Why ??

Comment: Is `img` an array?

Comment: Incidentally, the correct way to handle a single file is using `single`, not `any`.

Comment: it work with any. i need to take multiple image later thats way i am using any..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use req.files[0].originalname instead of req.files.originalname

Comment: thank You So much. originalname is now working but other isn't.. how i can got those ..                                                                                                  
          Filename, path, extension, size, mimetype..

Comment: its same
req.files[0].filename;    for file name
req.files[0].path;    for path
req.files[0].mimetype;    for  mimetype
req.files[0].size;    for  size
req.files[0].filename.substring(str.lastIndexOf("."));    for extension

Comment: Done !! Thanks Again.